# How to get sessionid instagram using javascript?

Tags: cookies, instagram, sessionid

I want to extract instagran sessionid using `document.cookies` to showing up the cookie but the sessionid is not showing up, only this mid=YdIkCAALAAHf5L950uIGxAkNWkV; ig_nrcb=1; csrftoken=jIVrrMmSxrQQ3dCAhv0IdFKwMyfK8Qa; ds_user_id=512215994096

Please someone you help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

It’s HTTP only which means that you can’t read it through JavaScript